# Javascript random number between coordinates

Tags: javascript, random

I would like to generate points between the following coordinates : `52.1462 ,5.8676 - 52.1536 ,5.8376`
This is where my rectangle is drawn.

I got the following code to randomize points between this rectangle:

```
var x_min = rectangle.getBounds().getEast();
var x_max = rectangle.getBounds().getWest();
var y_min = rectangle.getBounds().getSouth();
var y_max = rectangle.getBounds().getNorth();


var lat = y_min + (Math.random() * (y_max - y_min));
var lng = x_min + (Math.random() * (x_max - x_min));


lngBrd.push([l , b ]); == My starting point. 
lngBrd.push([lng, lat]); == should be random inside the box
lngBrd.push([lng, lat]); == should be random inside the box
```

But it gives me coordinates outside to box, see the img.

[image]

Where goes this wrong?

Reply to the comment

If I log :

```
lngBrd.push([l , b ]); == My starting point. 
lngBrd.push([lng, lat]); == should be random inside the box
lngBrd.push([lng, lat]); == should be random inside the box
```

I get :

[image]

On every refresh. (This first one is correct, because thats my starting point)

Comment: The image seems to be more random that the numbers. Can you please give an example of coordinates off the range in numbers instead of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `x_min` should be the `rectangle.getBounds().getWest();` and `x_max` should be `rectangle.getBounds().getEast();` assuming that we are in the 1st quadrant of a cartesian plane.

```
var x_min = rectangle.getBounds().getWest();
var x_max = rectangle.getBounds().getEast();
var y_min = rectangle.getBounds().getSouth();
var y_max = rectangle.getBounds().getNorth();
```

and since the coordinates are `(52.1462 ,5.8676)` `(52.1536 ,5.8376)` it might be useful to multiply the values first to `10000` then revert back after.

```
var x_min_int = x_min * 10000;
var x_max_int = x_max * 10000;
var y_min_int = y_min * 10000;
var y_max_int = y_max * 10000;

var lat_int = y_min_int + (Math.random() * (y_max_int - y_min_int));
var lng_int = x_min_int + (Math.random() * (x_max_int - x_min_int));

var lat = lat_int / 10000;
var lng = lng_int / 10000;
```

Since `Math.random()` works best on integers, proper randomization will work on the range of the rectangle

Comment: It gives me the same output as in the mine.  Yes that is correct.

Comment: how about using Math.floor(Math.random() * (equation))

Comment: I also tried that, but the two pushes with the new coordinates keeps giving me the numbers 4 and 5. How can it be that is constant 4 and 5, is the random function writen wrong or something? (It happens in my example and yours also

Comment: I think I got it, since your rectangle are decimal points apart, it might help to multiply first the coordinates to 10000 before computing the random values, then divide back.

Comment: Could you give an example on this last statement?

Comment: Thanks Sir, I think this is the right way. The output from `lat` and `lng` are now:
`53.300060433850135, 5.12649059749864` . But when I push `lat` and `lng` to my `Array` it still draws outside the box

Comment: I think the issue with your box, if I understand is that the y axis on programming languages are inverted. Just a hunch

Comment: This is my box:

`var bounds = [[ 52.1462 ,5.8676], [ 52.1536 ,5.8376]];     
  var rectangle = L.rectangle(bounds).addTo(this.map);`

I dont see the problem why my line goes outside the randomized numbers then?

Comment: Do I understand right that the box' bound itself is incorrect? or perhaps rounding the `lat` and `lng` to 4 decimal places can fix the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir, got it working. The reason why it didnt draw in the right rectangle was because I did `set` rectangle two times. Stupid mistake.

Again thanks!